# Javascript increment through elements within div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, increment

Ok, so I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="x"></p>
    <p class="y"></p>
</div>

<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="z"></p>
    <p class="a"></p>
</div>

<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="b"></p>
    <p class="c"></p>
</div>
```

I need to increment through each of these divs and compare classes that each `<p>` has.

How would I go about doing this?

Currently I have this:

```
$('.calculator-section').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).$('p').each(function(i, obj) { //This bit doesn't work
        //Check classes for $(this) here?
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure what to do for that inner loop. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of comparison you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `p` to your initial each loop and use the `className` property within the loop

```js
$('.calculator-section p').each(function(i, obj) {
    if(this.className == "x") {
       $(this).css('background', 'green')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="x">x</p>
    <p class="y">y</p>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you are using the multiple loops for a reason:

Select `p` within the iteration of specific section with  `$('p', this)` or `$(this).children('p')` etc

```js
$('.calculator-section').each(function(i, obj) {
    // $(this) = section
    $('p', this).each(function(i, obj) {     
        // $(this) = p within above section                
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single `each()` instead of double `each()`. Example here..

```
$('.calculator-section p').each(function(i, obj) {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    if(className == 'expected value'){
        //do something
        //return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to get too many results.  `<p class="x"><p>` should be `<p class="x"></p>` (with a forward slash to indicate closing the paragraph.

```
<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="x"></p>
    <p class="y"></p>
</div>

<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="z"></p>
    <p class="a"></p>
</div>

<div class="calculator-section">
    <p class="b"></p>
    <p class="c"></p>
</div>
```

Once that's fixed,

```
//you can grab the class couples this way
var results = $('.calculator-section').map(function(i, obj) {
    return $(obj).find('p').map(function(i, obj) {
        return obj.className;
    });
});

//and then do what you want with them later
results.each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj[0] + ',' + obj[1]);    
});

>> x,y
>> z,a
>> b,c
```

Comment: What's the reason for the -1?